# Application of Structure Theorem to Prove Simultaneous Diagonalizability and Group of Units of Cyclic Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I am reading [these](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/atm/final1.pdf) notes on Modules over PID.

Exercise 67 (pg 24) asks to prove that:

> **Problem.** Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries. Then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable and $AB=BA$.

Exercise 76 (pg 25) asks to prove that:

> **Problem.** Show that the group of units of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is cyclic if and only if $n$ is either $2$, or $4$, or a power of an odd prime.

I know proofs of both these problems which do not use structure theorem. But since these notes revolve around the structure theorem, I think may be these can be attacked via some interesting application of the same.

Can anybody see how the structure theorem can be used here, if at all?

Comment: For the second question, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276464/show-that-mathbbz-n-times-cannot-be-cyclic-unless-n-is-either-a-prime. Requiring to use the structure theorem would be pushing it, I think.